How should I negotiate authorship roles with Chinese collaborators to ensure fair recognition across different academic cultures?
I am a new lecturer at an Australian university, currently collaborating with Chinese scholars on a research project related to computer vision.
In this collaboration:
The Chinese collaborators provide students who are working on the project. The students' formal supervisors know little about this field, so I will supervise them, providing the main ideas and guiding the paper-writing process.
In my previous research, I was usually the first author. Now that I am a lecturer, I am unsure which authorship position would be most beneficial for my career advancement—first, last, or somewhere else.
From my discussions with Chinese collaborators, it seems they place the most importance on the corresponding author role but do not emphasize the order of other authors beyond the first author. I will not be the corresponding author for this project as I do not fund the students, but I have the flexibility to choose my author order (e.g. the last author).
My questions are:
How is authorship typically viewed in Australia, the US, and Europe? Specifically, which positions—first or last author—are most valued for career advancement?
Given that I can select my author order, what position would best reflect my role as the supervisor and idea contributor for the paper?
How can I ensure my contributions are appropriately recognized, considering the cultural differences in authorship between my collaborators and the academic expectations in Australia?
=============================================
I think it’s also worth providing some background. In my field, research on multimodal large language models has now become a major trend, but it’s extremely costly. Most universities lack the necessary GPUs to run experiments with LLMs, and individual lecturers, apart from a few well-known names in Australia, can’t afford the infrastructure either. One way to pursue this type of research is by collaborating with those who have access to these resources and are open to partnerships—most often based in the Middle East or China.

Please add the field you are working in, since author order meanings seem to differ quite between fields. E.g. in (pure) mathematics, in my experience none of these things carry any prestige at all. Order is alphabetical and the corresponding author is simply the one handling the bureaucracy - sometimes even to compensate for fewer contributions than the other authors ...

thanks, I just added it. We are working on a computer vision project, seeking to publish on CVPR, ICCV or Neurips, etc.

What is your actual field/domain? Computer vision can anything from CS, to lab sciences, to humanities. Are all of you in the same domain?

Yeah.. basically, we are currently working on multimodal vision large language models for tasks like visual question answering.

Apologies for the non-constructive comment, but: When I read this, I feel really so happy about how we do it in pure math...

Here is my advice. For career advancement you want to show that you can be creative and productive, and ultimately establish yourself as a "leader" (I don't like this term because it is too much pressure to become a leader in just 5 years) in your area.
Collaborations are also great. It shows that you are building a network, and this network should help sustain your career development.
However, based on your description I see a couple of red flags. First, it seems like you are the one running the creative end of this project, yet you are deferring to your collaborators to become corresponding authors just because they supply funding. This is not acting like you are faculty, this is postdoc behavior. If you are doing the creative work, then you deserve to be one of the corresponding authors (at least). Frankly I would argue you should be the only one if they are not going to be significantly engaged in writing at the end.
At this point of your career, you should be focusing on building your portfolio. You should be recruiting and guiding your students (not someone else's), and definitely not in another country that is largely (and accurately) seen as a competitor. At this point, time and energy spent on a paper where you are some random middle author will do nothing for you. Unless your goal is to seek faculty opportunities in China, where deference to those senior faculty may pave the way, you should be focused on yourself.
When you are faculty, you are judged on your creative works, and the way you claim them is by being the corresponding author.

Thanks for the advice. The problem is that I don't have the funding to support running the large language model, neither do most of the young lectures in Australia. Now we have to seek collaboration in middle-east(they are super rich!), China or the US. Chinese collaborators happen to provide good resources this time. I also have collaborators in the Middle East, but reaching out to US collaborators isn't easy. They usually have plenty of resources so that they won't collaborate with us. I asked my previous supervisors. They told me, "It is now just better than nothing".

But you're absolutely right. I just started my faculty career about 20 days ago, and I’m working on transitioning from my role as a postdoc to becoming a fully-fledged faculty member. My biggest challenge right now is finding resources to overcome the lack of GPU access and stay on top of the latest technological advancements.

@hidemyname if you are relinquishing your creative rights (corresponding authorship) for some money, then you are collaborating with unethical, predatory scientists. If those people even think that it is OK to let a young faculty lead a project and not insist that the young faculty also take corresponding authorship (or at least share it), then they are unethical. I understand you are starved for resources, but you would even be better off working within your limits (but independently or in the lead) rather than essentially working as a postdoc for some faculty in China.

I am not sure corresponding authorship is such a big deal in the field @hidemyname mentions (publishing at CVPR, ICCV, NeurIPS). In my experience the first and last author positions have importance, the corresponding author is just someone who can be expected to respond to emails (and is often the first author who is usually a student).

@GoodDeeds
I’ve never been in either of these roles—corresponding or last author. Chinese academics seem to place a lot of importance on being the corresponding author, but they don’t seem to care much about author order. I’m not sure why that is. Maybe a good way is to let them correspond, and I will be the last.
